# PhpStorm passively listen to requests

Tags: php, python, json, phpstorm, xdebug

I want to debug a php script using PhpStorm 10 and xdebug. My setup is as following:

1. The client side is in python. The client sends json data. The code for the client is( contact is a variable containing a json):

   ```
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('192.168.2.103:85')
   headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "charset" : "utf-8"}
   body = json.dumps(contact, ensure_ascii = 'False')
   conn.request('POST', '/web_service/index.php', body, headers)
   response = conn.getresponse()
   ```
2. The server side is in php. On the server side I setup the xdebug as following:

   ```
   zend_extension = "E:\_Dizertatie\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
   xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
   xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "E:\_Dizertatie\tmp"
   xdebug.remote_enable =true
   xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
   xdebug.remote_port = 9000
   ```

Using this [guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) and this [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) I was able to debug my page only when I was starting the "start debug" bookmarklet. My python requests are not caught in the debugger of PhpStorm. I want passively listen( not using bookmarklets) and catch in the php debugger all the request no matter their source (python, mobile, different php script).

Is there a configuration that I can use to debug the php script when sending python request?

Comment: You need to tell xdebug that you want to debug this request. This is exactly what bookmarkets/browser extensions do -- they set xdebug cookie that is sent together with next page request. You can replace cookie by actual GET or POST parameter via [XDEBUG_SESSION_START](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote). Alternatively you can tell xdebug to debug every single request automatically (`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`) which can be undesired and may have some side effects (e.g. approx 1 sec delay if debug client is not available). That's to go with zero config you are using already.

Comment: @LazyOne by setting the xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 in the php.ini didn't work. I used the method in which I send  XDEBUG_SESSION_START and this did work. Thank you. P.S please answer so that I can check your answer as resolved

Comment: Did you restart your web server (or php-fpm if you are using it) after making changes in php.ini? Otherwise it is very unlikely that those changes will be picked up automatically until restart.

Comment: It worked. I was living with the impression of restarting the server. Both solutions worked. Thank you

Comment: @LazyOne please answer so I can check as resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell xdebug that you want to debug this request.

This is exactly what bookmarkets/browser extensions do -- they set xdebug cookie that is sent together with next page request. You can replace cookie by actual GET or POST parameter via [XDEBUG_SESSION_START](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) -- e.g. add such parameter to your `conn.request(...` line.

---

Alternatively you can tell xdebug to **debug every single request automatically** (via `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your `php.ini`) which can be undesired and may have some "side effects" (approx 1 sec delay in execution if debug client is not available -- the time xdebug waits for possible client to respond). That's to go with [zero config approach](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) (the "phone handle" icon) you are using already.

If you are using this option then do not forget to restart your web server (or `php-fpm` if you are using it) after making changes in php.ini. Otherwise it is very unlikely that those changes will be picked up automatically until restart (by default in most setups).

---

**P.S.**
PhpStorm has built-in simple [REST Client](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Built-in+REST+Client+in+PhpStorm) accessible via `Tools | Test RESTful Web Service` which you can use to send custom requests (instead of using your real client side (python code in your case)).

Since **PhpStorm v11** (will be released soon) you can initiate debug directly from there (dedicated "Debug" button) instead of adding xdebug cookie/query parameters.

Another alternative is to use similar browser-based tool (e.g. Postman for Chrome).